# Creating an exe in python

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, py2exe

I have created a gui using tkinter in python 2.7 and I wish to create a executable for this code. From what I understand I need to use py2exe. My question is if I create the executable will it still pull up the gui interface or will it be in the cmd prompt?

Comment: yes, It will prompt the gui.

Comment: Thank you. I think I just misunderstood the instructions in py2exe.

Comment: Use `pyinstaller` its simple and very easy to use.